# mysql utilities - path setup

Tags: python, mysql, path

I'm using the MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47 utilties, and I'm trying to get mysqldbexport to run from a directory other than where it's installed (in my case, `D:\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\utilities`).  I notice that even the shell started by the Workbench doesn't work if I CD out of the utilities directory.

I am in the process of setting up a BAT file that can run mysqldbexport from any directory, but now I'm getting the "ImportError: No module named site" error.  To me this looks like the Python included in MySQL can't find its stuff - what environment variables do I need to set to fix this?